# Routing issues with High Voltage and locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, high-voltage

My routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope "(:locale)", locale: /fr-FR|de-DE|es-ES|zh-CN/ do
    get ":id" => "high_voltage/pages#show", as: :page, format: false
...
```

Which works fine for things on the top level like `/pricing` however pages nested inside folders (e.g. `/pricing/products`) get routes like `/zh-CN/pricing%2Fproducts` (which routes correctly, but looks ugly) and also `/zh-CN/pricing/products` does not route correctly

Answer (score 1):

```
get "*id" => "high_voltage/pages#show", as: :page, format: false
```

in my routes file fixes the issue